# nginx rewrite rule explanation

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

begin whith a example.

Input URI:

`http://website.com/search/some-search-keywords`

Rewritten URI:

`http://website.com/search.php?q=some-search-keywords`

Rewrite rule:

`rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1?`

What is the meaning of "?" in the "Rewrite rule" ？I am do not understand 
someone can give me a explain or reference？thanks very much!

Comment: Which "?"? There's one before and one after the query string. The latter should probably be removed.

Comment: oh,sorry,I mean that all "?" in the "Rewrite rule:",the first one behind "/search.php"and the last one , also

Comment: oh,sorry,I mean that all "?" in the "Rewrite rule:",the first one behind "/search.php"and the last one , also that in the end of the "rewrite ^search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1?" should be a ";" that like this "rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1?;",this example is a excerpt from the book "nginx http server" and which is recommend by http://www.nginx.org/en/books.html,so the laste "?"  probably should not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

http://nginx.org/r/rewrite

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended

Reading official documentation is always a good idea.